# "(TS) Call target does not contain any signatues" on call to super constructor with props

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I get the error *Call target does not contain any signatures* on **super(props);**.

Would anybody please explain what does the error mean and how to fix it? Ty

```
declare var require: any
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');

class Button extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { count: 0 };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <button> CLICK ME </button>    
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Button />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Replace this piece of code:***

```
declare var require: any
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
```

***... with:***

```
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";
```

***Your entire new code will now look like this:***

```
// declare var require: any
// var React = require('react');
// var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";

class Button extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { count: 0 };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <button> CLICK ME </button>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Button />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: Ty for your feedback.

There is yet another error: **Property 'state' does not exist on type 'Button'** Do I have to declare the var elsewhere?

Comment: You may need to install `types/react` npm package. https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/react

Comment: Ok. I've also removed my last comment to leave things clean. I will remove this comment after you remove your last one if you will. Ty.